# Cannot suspend HikariCP

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, hikaricp

The exception is thrown when trying to suspend HikariCP pool while simulating network connection fail for a couple of seconds. Why can the pool cannot be suspended? Are there other easy ways to simulate lost network connection (to MySQL server on localhost)?

**Configuration:**

```
final String configFile = "src/main/resources/db.properties";
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(configFile);
config.setRegisterMbeans(true);
config.setPoolName("hikari-pool-1");
ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

**Properties:**

```
jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?user=user&password=password
dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
dataSource.useServerPrepStmts=true
dataSource.useLocalSessionState=true
dataSource.useLocalTransactionState=true
dataSource.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
dataSource.cacheResultSetMetadata=true
dataSource.cacheServerConfiguration=true
dataSource.elideSetAutoCommits=true
dataSource.maintainTimeStats=false
```

**JUnit**:

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName poolName = new ObjectName("com.zaxxer.hikari:type=Pool (hikari-pool-1)");
HikariPoolMXBean poolProxy = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mBeanServer, poolName, HikariPoolMXBean.class);
poolProxy.suspendPool();
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: hikari-pool-1 - is not suspendable
```

Comment: To compliment the answers below, suspending a pool will not cause any exceptions to be thrown; it will simply block new connection requests until the pool is resumed.

Answer (score 5):

By default suspension of the pool is not allowed, you need to explicitly enable pool suspension.

See also the [documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP):

> ❎`allowPoolSuspension`
>   This property controls whether the pool can
>   be suspended and resumed through JMX. This is useful for certain
>   failover automation scenarios. When the pool is suspended, calls to
>   `getConnection()` will not timeout and will be held until the pool is
>   resumed. *Default: false*

In short, add:

```
config.setAllowPoolSuspension(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

These are all great answers.  Unfortunately, suspending the pool is *not* a good way of simulating a network outage.  Depending on whether you are on Windows, Linux, or Mac, there are likely different options.

On Linux, the best way to simulate a network failure is to enable/disable a firewall rule that *DROPS* (not DENY) traffic to the MySQL port.  It would go *something* like this (check online references):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

And disabling (removing the block) would go something like this:

```
iptables -D INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```